# Install gnuplot with tex option while already installed with x11 option

Tags: installation, latex, gnuplot

On my mac, I have installed
XQuartz (x11)
homebrew 
gnuplot
gcc
latex

I have installed gnuplot with the following option `--with-x11`.

I would like to allow the use of gnuplot on latex. Should I only do `brew install gnuplot --with-tex` or is it going to redundant.

I am pretty new to the terminal, gnuplot ...etc and I do not want to do anything stupid.

Thanks a lot for your help and sorry if the question has already been asked.

Bests

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it via homebrew or compiled it from source? Keep in mind you can view all options for homebrew recipes with

```
brew options gnuplot
```

these options are passed to the `gnuplot` configuration prior to compilation (they need to be enabled at compile-time).  You'll find that a `--with-tex` option doesn't exist because `gnuplot` enables it by default.  For a more complete set of compile-time options, some of which aren't available via homebrew, getting the `gnuplot` sourcecode and running `./configure -h` in the source directory will tell you the available options and defaults:

```
...
--without-latex         disable latex support, (default enable)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

run gnuplot
   set terminal latex
    you can check it by setting windows by
set terminal window
plot